# Troubleshooting XP Network Connection

Tags: networking, windows-xp, internet-explorer

Attempts to update Windows XP (fresh install) indicates Windows is unable to access the NIC (see second screen capture).  The XP native web browser (IE) is also having network connectivity problems: unable to resolve mail.google.com.  I need gmail connectivity on this machine.

Attempts to ping yahoo.com were successful. I think a successful reply from yahoo indicates DNS functionality and internet connectivity are confirmed to be functional.

Suggestions to start troubleshooting are appreciated: thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you're not using a proper web browser. You may even be using something worse than the IE that comes with XP.  You say you can ping www.yahoo.com  Try to Open Internet Explorer and try to go to www.yahoo.com

Comment: I'm not sure waht you mean by XP's native web browser.. and I hardly ever used the "help and support centre". Try opening IE. And try getting an offline download of chrome put it on a usb stick and install it on that computer. Or Opera(another web browser), or firefox..

Comment: To say you're unable to access the NIC but can access the Internet, is complete nonsense and makes no sense at all

Comment: @barlop thanks for suggestions.  I needed to add a clarifying screenshot.  The second screenshot shows that XP thinks there is no Internet connection despite the fact I can ping yahoo.com from the command line.  IE redirects yahoo to bing.

Comment: No XP machine has been connected to the network around here since 2013 or so (end of support.) It's pure insanity to do so; one or two are still running, but they are very carefully isolated from the network.. IE (a very old IE) is of course the native web browser for XP, Windows updates may well not be there for XP, since support ended years ago.

Comment: when you say IE redirects yahoo to bing.. Do you mean IE can access bing?  And it seems a bit strange the idea that IE would redirect to bing ot try to.. perhaps it thinks you are searching rather than going to an address. Are you putting http:// in the address bar, or search terms as if  the address bar is a search engine? Try putting http:// in there with the yahoo address so http://www.yahoo.com so treat the address bar like an address bar, like people always used to do. maybe www.yahoo.com in there but http:// with it to make sure. Certainly not just yahoo in there.

Comment: @barlop Yes: address bar (not search terms): http:// www.bing.com works as does http:/ /www.msn.com    It's odd that http://mail.google.com => 'The page cannot be displayed'  Space in http:// were necessary for this message.

Comment: I feel the need to understand the underlying issue and look forward to any diagnostic qeustions

Comment: @gatorback maybe there's a compatibility issue with `mail.google.com` and IE6. How about if you try gmail.com? or going to www.google.com then clicking on gmail?  (could still be a compatibility issue there so in which case those won't work and will give the same error) .Try firefox and chrome. You can even download them since you clearly have internet access. That will help both diagnose and understand or confirm the underlying issue as far as we can determine it.

Comment: and if it turns out to be gmail not working on it but other websites working then definitely that gmail dropped IE6 support http://www.computerworld.com/article/2520539/web-apps/gmail-to-drop-ie6-support-this-year.html  And by the way, as far as diagnosis is concerned, that "help and support centre" screenshot is not very useful!

Comment: www.google.com would not work with IE.  I was hoping to avoid installing Firefox and upgrading to IE7, however, in the interest of time, I installed Firefox and it seems to work with gmail.  Although the web browsing is overcome with FF, I do not think this resolve the underlying problem where windows is unable to access WAN resources (updates)

Comment: Which service pack, if any, was included with the installation disk?  If the answer isn't sp3 you should download that on a different PC and copy it on to this one. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322389

Answer (score 0):

try to look at hosts file (location:"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc")
compare content of the file with default (in default it is only one record "127.0.0.1 localhost").